# Is there a way to turn off all Google Cast logging?

Tags: google-cast

I've set:

> GCKLogger.sharedInstance().loggingEnabled = false

But I still see this printed out every time a Google Cast button appears on the page. It really pollutes my output log and is annoying (This is in GoogleCast framework version 3.5.0 / cast.ios.sdk_20170313.00_RC49):

```
> 2017-05-29 16:34:04.250 appName[22378:1706584] Logging 10, currently
> detected {(
>     1,
>     5 )}
```

Comment: Seems there's no way of doing this from the [google cast docs](https://developers.google.com/cast/). All I keep seeing is how to turn off [annoying cast notifications](https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/7206638?hl=en) which is far from what you're asking.